# Efficiently calculate index of specific element in lexicographical ordering

Tags: c++, indexing, element, lexicographic

I have four elements:

```
A B C D
```

I can arrange all permutations of `n elements` in lexicographical ordering, so for `n=2`:

```
0=AA 1=AB 2=AC 3=AD ... 15=DD
```

How can I, without resorting to counting, calculate the index in this ordering for a specific element?

When I enumerate my elements `0=A 1=B 2=C 3=D` and have a string `string` I can calculate the index like this for `n=2`

```
4 * val(string[0]) + val(string[1])
string="AC" -> 4*0 + 2 = 2
string="DD" -> 4*3 + 3 = 15
```

How can I find the index for any string and `n > 2`? I only really need it for `n=2,3,4,5`, but it feels like there should be a general solution that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it just

```
(4 ^ (n - 1)) * val(string[0])
+ (4 ^ (n - 2)) * val(string[1])
+ ...
+ (4 ^ (0)) * val(string[n-1])
```

You'd probably program that with a loop.

Comment: Ah thanks, so it really was this simple. Must have been too tired to find this myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you change these letters {A, B, C, D} to numbers {0, 1, 2, 3}, you will find that it is just quaternary notation, or suppose you have 10 letters {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J} and change them to 0 -- 9, it will be like our familiar decimal notation. So, in quaternary system, AA = 00, DD = 33, changing into decimal will be 3*4+3=15, BC's index will be 1*4+2 = 6.